# Powershell memory load percentage

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I currently have this script which I am trying to get to display the % of processor load. Its returns results and seemingly reports correctly but it doesnt show the actual % in the output:

SCRIPT:

```
$Servers = Get-QADComputer -sizelimit 0 | where {$_.Name -like "*MYSERVER*"} | select Name | sort name
# Best practice: avoid magic numbers; readonly variable for 
new-variable -name CPULIMIT -value 75 -option readonly

foreach($Server in $Servers){
$result = Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $Server.Name
# TODO: add error handler here in case $server is unavailable
# Compare the wmi query result to the limit constant
if($result.LoadPercentage -le $CPULIMIT){
    # Write a formatted string that contains the server name and current load
    Write-Host $("Less than 75% Processor Load on {0} ({1}%)" -f $server.name, $result.LoadPercentage) -ForegroundColor "Green"
} else {
    # A warning message would be usefull too
    Write-Host $("More than 75% Processor Load on {0} ({1}%)" -f $server.name, $result.LoadPercentage) -ForegroundColor "Red"
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Less than 75% CPU Load on MYSERVER1 (%)
 Less than 75% CPU Load on MYSERVER2 (%)
 Less than 75% CPU Load on MYSERVER3 (%)
 Less than 75% CPU Load on MYSERVER4 (%)
```

As you can see there is now over all (%) displayed.

Any ideas would be greatly apprecaited.

Thanks

Comment: Check to see if $result.LoadPercentange is null or an empty string.  Your string formatting is correct so it should display the value - does for me on localhost.

Comment: Not empty. Just noticed it displays a result for 2 servers just not the rest. Really confused! :(

Comment: I'm guessing more than one cpu is returned. Try this: $result[0].LoadPercentage

Comment: On a multi-core/multi-thread machine, there will be a collection of LoadPercentage. One for each virtual CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Z adjustement of $result[0].LoadPercentage worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like $result[0] gets you one of multiple processors, and you might want an average.